# Install authentication in laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm proceeding with the first installation of Laravel 8, everything is ok, I also installed the authentication system via commands:

```
composer require laravel/ui

php artisan ui vue --auth
```

Unfortunately, I can't find any auth folders on the controller.
Furthermore, there is also no auth.php route
Can you tell me how to do it? How do I proceed?

PS: I would also like not to rely on any UI as bootstrap or whatever, but on my assets css and js. (I hope I have explained)

Comment: The Auth Controllers are under App > Http > Auth > you find your all auth controllers here. The routes are defined in web.php and not in auth.php.

Comment: I know this, my problem is that unfortunately I don't know how to create them. Both controllers and routers are not present. Only the User.php model is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `php artisan ui:controllers` to scaffold the auth controllers.

Comment: Perfect, to generate the route instead?